# Upload file to Google Drive from PhoneGap iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, google-drive-api

In my iPhone app, I am generating a text file. I want to upload that file to Google Drive.

The app is built in PhoneGap.

Is there any API/plugin for this?

I am referring to this link:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js, but when I integrated this into my app, it will redirect to Safari for authentication.

Is there any process that will run in the background to upload files to Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

> On iOS, query fetches will normally be stopped once the user puts the application into the background. Fetches and callbacks can be continued in the background, up to the operating system time limit, by setting the property shouldFetchInBackground:

service.shouldFetchInBackground = YES;